# insert formula with vba into excel

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I need to add this formula into a range of rows via VBA

```
=WENN(ISTNV(VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&"*"&Januar!B1:B99=A16&"*"&B16);Januar!D:D));" ";VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&"*"&Januar!B1:B99=A16&"*"&B16);Januar!D:D))
```

its german, but the only thing that matters, is that i need to replace the 16 with the loop variable **i**

```
For i = 17 To Rows.Count
Cells(14, i).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ISTNV(VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&"*"&Januar!B1:B99=A"&i"&""*""&B""&i"");Januar!D:D));"" "";VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&""*""&Januar!B1:B99=A""i""&""*""&B""i"");Januar!D:D))"
Next
```

I read some articles but i doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: you need to use double ampersands on both sites and add spaces before and after. Something like this: `"=(A16)"` >> `"=(A" & i & ")"`. Sugestion: select each `16` and paste `" & i & "` instead.

Comment: Cells(14, i).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ISTNV(VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&"" * ""&Januar!B1:B99=A"" & i & ""&"" * ""&B"" & i & "");Januar!D:D));"" "";VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&"" * ""&Januar!B1:B99=A"" & i & ""&"" * ""&B"" & i & "");Januar!D:D))"

Comment: thanks but im getting a runtime error now :/

Answer (score 1):

The formula string is a string literal enclosed in double quotes `"`. We can concatenate variables into that string using `&`. We can have double quotes within the string if we do escaping them by duplicating.

Examples:

```
Dim s as String
Dim i as Integer
i = 123

s = "Test " & i & " Test"

s = "Test """ & i & """ Test"
```

In your special case the additional difficulty is that you have not only `&` as the concatenating operator in `VBA` but also within the formula string. This leads to confusion. I recommend to create the formula string first within a string variable. So you can `Debug.print` this string and check.

```
For i = 17 To Rows.Count
 sFormula = "=WENN(ISTNV(VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&""*""&Januar!B1:B99=A" & i & "&""*""&B" & i & ");Januar!D:D));"" "";VERWEIS(2;1/(Januar!A1:A99&""*""&Januar!B1:B99=A" & i & "&""*""&B" & i & ");Januar!D:D))"
 Debug.Print sFormula
 Cells(i, 14).FormulaLocal = sFormula
Next
```

Btw.: Within `Cells` the first parameter is the row index and the second parameter is the column index. So according to your code (`i` is the row  number) it should be `Cells(i, 14)`.

Btw.: I recommend not to use `FormulaLocal` but `Formula` and the English function names and English formula notation (comma as the parameter delimiter instead of semicolon). This will be more locale independent.

Answer (score 1):

Axel gave you the solution

building on it you may want to adopt `FomulaLocalR1C1` property to simplify your formula:

for instance:

```
=A" & i & "&""*""&B" & i
```

would become:

```
"=RC1 & ""*"" & RC2"
```

or

```
"=VERKETTEN(RC1;""*"";RC2)"
```

in such a scenario you'd have to turn all range references to `R1C1` notation so that:

```
Januar!A1:A99

Januar!B1:B99
```

become:

```
Januar!R1C1:R99C1
Januar!R1C2:R99C2
```

Comment: Hm, good point in general. But `"=CONCATENATE(RC1;""*"";RC2)"` will only work using `FomulaLocalR1C1` if the locale is English GB. In German locale it would must be `"=VERKETTEN(RC1;""*"";RC2)"`. That's why my recommendation **not** to use the `FormulaLocal...` but `Formula...` always. In case of `R1C1` `FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: @AlexRichter, you're right for the `Concatenate` option. Thank you

Comment: @Beatrice, did you get through it?